# How in COnvert JSON webservice values into a HTML page using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON Format Page and a HTML page.
In JSON format page I have employee data.
In HTML page if I click on Submit Button, the page have to show the values of JSON Format into Table format.

In .html page I added reference of .js files. After that I write code like

```
<table id="EmpNewTable" border="2"> 
<tr> 
  <th>First Name</th> 
</tr> 
</table><br /><br /> 
<input type="button" id="DisplyEmp" value="Display" onclick="test();" />
```

and in test() method what code do I have to write? I tried using `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON` but values are not displaying

my json page is

```
{"SelectEmployeeResult": [
{
"Address":"Pune",
"DateOfBirth1":"11\/11\/1988 12:00:00 AM",
 "FirstName":"Balaji",
"LastName":"Nikam",
"Sex":"Male"
}, 
{
  "Address":"Hyd", 
  "DateOfBirth1":"11\/4\/1988 12:00:00 AM",
  "FirstName":"jaya",
  "LastName":"deokar",
  "Sex":"Female"
}, 
.
.
.
```

Comment: share your json and html code

Comment: In .html page i added reference of .js files after tht i write code like <table id="EmpNewTable" border="2">
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>  
    
    </table>  
    

    <br /><br />
   <input type="button" id="DisplyEmp" value="Display" onclick="test();" />and in test() method what code i have to write?i tired using $.ajax and $.getJSON but values is not displaying

Comment: my json page is {"SelectEmployeeResult":
[{"Address":"Pune","DateOfBirth1":"11\/11\/1988 12:00:00 AM","FirstName":"Balaji","LastName":"Nikam","Sex":"Male"},
{"Address":"Hyd","DateOfBirth1":"11\/4\/1988 12:00:00 AM","FirstName":"jaya","LastName":"deokar","Sex":"Female"},

Comment: Have a look around, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968651/jquery-nested-getjson-not-working

Comment: $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:50506/Service1.svc/SelectEmployee",
              context: document.body,
              success: function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function (i, json) {
                      alert('sadasd');
                      $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + json.FirstName + '</td><td>' + json.LastName + '</td><td>' + json.Address + '</td><td>' + json.DateOfBirth1 +
                      '</td><td>' + json.Sex + ' </td></tr>');
                      
                  });

              }..still iam dont getting values in output user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get value with $.getJSON like this,

```
$.getJSON("stackjson.json", function(data) {
    for(emp in data.SelectEmployeeResult) {
        //iterate array here
        alert(data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].FirstName); 
    } 
});
```

here is whole working code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#DisplyEmp").click(function() {
          $.getJSON("yourjsonurl", function(data) {
              for(emp in data.SelectEmployeeResult) {
                  console.log(data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp]);
                  var newRow = "<tr>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].FirstName+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].LastName+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].DateOfBirth1+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].Sex+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.SelectEmployeeResult[emp].Address+"</td>"+
                               "</tr>";
                  $("#EmpNewTable").append(newRow);
              } 
          });
      });
  });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<table id="EmpNewTable" border="2"> 
<tr> 
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Birthday</th>
  <th>Sex</th>
  <th>Address</th>
</tr> 
</table><br /><br /> 
<input type="button" id="DisplyEmp" value="Display" />

</body></html>
```

and result like this,

[image]